# How to downvote a comment?

Tags: discussion

I was looking this question [Why did Mace Windu and the Jedi Council refuse to raise Anakin to the rank of Master?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226416/why-did-mace-windu-and-the-jedi-council-refuse-to-raise-anakin-to-the-rank-of-ma)

But the only way to downvote a comment is to flag it. That seems very counter intuitive, as the comment may be valid to a certain extent , but I just don't agree with it.

How do I downvote a comment?

Comment: I'd take a peek here, downvotes on comments has been discussed since basically the inception of the site. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/allow-downvoting-comments

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to downvote a comment, you can only upvote them. Please do not flag a comment to “downvote it”, that is not its purpose. Flagging is if there is something wrong with the comment and it needs deleting.

If the comment is wrong and would warrant a downvote if you could then just reply to the comment with one of your own explaining as such.

Comment: So why is there no comment downvote?

Comment: @KyloRen you’d have to ask SE that...

Comment: I can't , I am on a question ban.

Comment: @KyloRen I think that it i has to do with the purpose of comments.  They aren't primarily meant for arguments between visitors, they are meant to be helpful to the author of the question / answer.  Upvoting a comment means that you think it's helpful, and that you agree with it.  Downvoting a comment could be anything - you think it's rude, lame, doesn't cite a page number, anything.  Without an explanation, a comment downvote isn't helpful to the author of the Q/A, so you might as well just post a counter-comment instead.  Low opinions of comments are best left to the Q/A author alone.